# Flash storing strings as keys in array

Tags: flash, arrays, actionscript, actionscript-2

in php I could do:

```
$prices['ford']['mondeo']['2005'] = 4500;
$prices['ford']['mondeo']['2006'] = 5500;
$prices['ford']['mondeo']['2007'] = 7000;
```

and could do:

```
echo sizeof($prices['ford']); // output 1
echo sizeof($prices['ford']['mondeo']) //output 3
```

how can I achieve it in Flash. 
Flash doesn't seems to like STRINGS as ARRAY KEYS, does IT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have associative array -like functionality, you can use an `Object`;

```
var prices:Object = new Object();
prices.ford = new Object();
prices.ford.mondeo = new Object();
prices.ford.mondeo['2005'] = 4500;
prices.ford.mondeo['2006'] = 5500;
prices.ford.mondeo['2007'] = 7000;
```

or simply

```
var prices:Object = {
  ford: {
    mondeo: {
      2005: 4500,
      2006: 5500,
      2007: 7000
    }
  }
};
```

Actionscript doesn't have a built in function resembling `sizeof` in php, but you can easily write one of your own:

```
function sizeof(o:Object):Number {
    var n:Number = 0;
    for (var item in o)
        n++;
    return n;
}
```

And just use it like in php:

```
trace(sizeof(prices['ford'])); // traces 1
trace(sizeof(prices['ford']['mondeo'])); // traces3
```

Comment: Oh, you didn't state which version of as you're using in your question...:) I think you can just leave the :* part out in as2.

Comment: Edited the function into an AS2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are indexed by integers in Flash, if you want to index on a string use an Object instead.

Comment: can u give me example ?

are these objects easily accesible ? 
is there a equivalent of PUSH() & LENGTH() for Objects ??

Comment: ok  I got it :)  THANKS 

BUT....

how can I do N level Objects to store data
`events['abc']=Array(Array('yes','no'))`
what command will add another array to events['abc'] ??

Comment: `events.abc.push('may be');` But remember that after this line events.abc contains `[['yes', 'no'], 'may be']` instead of `['yes', 'no', 'may be']` as you might expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array:Array = [];
array['name'] = "the name";
array['something'] = "something else";
trace(array.length);
```

It traces 0. So yeah, flash doesn't really like strings as array keys though it is allowed. `Array` is a [dynamic class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/statements.html#dynamic) (like `Object`) where you can add properties to individual objects as you want. `array['name'] = "myname"` is same as `array.name = "myname"`.

That said, you can assign an array to `array['name']` and read its length.

```
var array:Array = [];
array['name'] = new Array();
array.name.push(1, 2, 3);
trace(array.length);//traces 0
trace(array.name.length);//traces 3
```